# Insert data in several table using single JPA query

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa-2.0

I want to create JPA queries for risk filters using several tables. I have these tables which I would like to use for storing data:

Risk filter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_filters")
public class RiskFilters implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -31232741713890134L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer terminal_id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String filter_class;

    @Column(name = "FILTER_SETTINGS", columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 65535)
    private String filter_settings;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer position;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer parent_id;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column
    private TemporalType updated_at;
    .....
}
```

Risk params:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_parameters")
public class RiskParameters implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6828168899788931021L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer payment_transaction_id;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 128)
    private String value;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime created_at;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime updated_at;
    ....
}
```

Risk Details:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_details")
public class RiskDetails implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6122869200132217334L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length = 4)
    private Integer payment_transaction_id;

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String service_name;

    @Column(length = 64)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 512)
    private String value;
    .....
}
```

How I can insert data into these entities with single insert and get data with single select?

I would like to use JPA in order to get and insert data.

Comment: can you explain about the dependency among all tables?

Comment: An INSERT in SQL inserts into a single table, not multiple. And? Post what you have tried and what is the "problem" ? (apart from the fact that you have no relationships so are using JPA for something that it is not suited for)

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I have one main table RiskFilters and additional RiskParameters and RiskDetails. In order to store many configuration values I need to use SQL one SQL queries in order to use them. Can you propose Insert and select for them?

Comment: You are using an Object Relational Mapper the purpose of which is prevent the need for manually creating SQL statements. You should then redefine your question, clearly explaining the relationship between the entities.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible if you have relation between tables(`risk_filters`,`risk_parameters` & `risk_details`) i.e. **primary key** and **foreign key** relationship.

Suppose **risk_filters** has one to one relationship with **risk_parameters** & **risk_details**, then the Entity will be look like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "risk_filters")
public class RiskFilters implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -31232741713890134L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
private int id;

@Column(length = 4)
private Integer terminal_id;

@Column(length = 255)
private String filter_class;

@Column(name = "FILTER_SETTINGS", columnDefinition = "TEXT", length = 65535)
private String filter_settings;

@Column(length = 4)
private Integer position;

@Column(length = 4)
private Integer parent_id;

@Column
private LocalDateTime created_at;

@Column
private TemporalType updated_at;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="risk_filter_id", nullable=false)
private RiskParameters riskParameters;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="risk_filter_id", nullable=false)
private RiskDetails riskDetails;
.....
}
```

and the call save method to save only **RiskFilters** Entity as below.

```
riskFilterObject.setRiskDetails(riskDetailsObject);
riskFilterObject.setRiskParamarets(riskParametersObject);
repository.save(riskFilterObject);// update 3 tables
repository.save(riskDetailsObject); // update only risk_details table
repository.save(riskParametersObject);// update only risk_parameters table
```

**Update:**

> How about select? Can you show me how to implement select from all
>   entities?

`RiskFilters  filters = riskFiltersRepository.findOne(id);`
 // for Complete netsed **RiskFilters** Entity object 
`RiskParameter  param = riskParameterRepository.findOne(id);`
 // for only **RiskParameter** Entity object 
`RiskDetails details = riskDetailsRepository.findOne(id);` 
// for only  **RiskDetails** Entity object

Comment: Yes but I have filter with 2 and filter with 8 settings. I have to use different tables for different cases.

Comment: if you want to save R.Param & R.Details individually u can do that, it wont affect Risk_filter as we haven't mapped bidirectionally.

Comment: Ok, can you show me JPA example using my entities in my original post?

Comment: How about select? Can you show me how to implement select from all entities?

Comment: Is there a way to use JOIN?

Comment: yes you can use join either JPA query of native query in repository methods by annotating *@Query*

Comment: This will be like  `@Query("SELECT  filter.col1 FROM  RiskFilters filter
  INNER JOIN RiskDetails details ON details.colKey= filter.colPrimary")` or you can use native query like:  `@Query("SQL Query", nativeQuery="true")`